# Javascript click function not working in IE 8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, client-side

I have a javascript function that works for Chrome, Firefox, and IE 11, but not for IE 8, which is what my client uses.

```
function ToggleSelectAll(this_id) {

    var chk = document.getElementById(this_id).childNodes[0];
    var lblID = "lblSelectAll" + chk.id.slice(-1);
    var lbl = document.getElementById(lblID);
    var items = $(lbl).closest('div.segment_container')[0].childNodes;
    if (document.getElementById(chk.id).checked == false) {
        lbl.innerHTML = "Select All";

        for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            if (items[i].className == "checkbox") {
                var bx = $(items[i]).children()[0];
                bx.checked = false;
                var label = $(items[i]).children()[1];
                label.style.background = '#CCC';
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        lbl.innerHTML = "Clear All";

        for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            if (items[i].className == "checkbox") {
                var bx = $(items[i]).children()[0];
                bx.checked = true;
                var label = $(items[i]).children()[1];
                label.style.background = '#C1ECFA';
        }
        }
    }
};
```

The function is run via onclick of a div. chk is a checkbox inside div that, when checked, selects/deselects all checkboxes within the parent container. I've tried replacing the .childnodes with .children and .firstElementChild, but it didn't help. Through the debugger, I can see that the values for chk, lblID, and lbl are the same in IE as they are in Chrome

**Edit**

Here is the jsfiddle with some relevant html: http://jsfiddle.net/zNEyb/1/

Comment: plz create a jsfiddle for the above code..showing the problem

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: jquery-1.7.2.min.js. I am mixing jQuery with DOM API because I am a beginner to both and wrote the script while learning.

Comment: How did you attach the Event? Please show us. If you are using jQuery, why the plain JavaScript?

Comment: FYI, this `if (document.getElementById(chk.id).checked == false)` can just be this: `if (!chk.checked)`.  You already have the DOM object - no need to get it's id and then search for it again.

Comment: Please show the HTML.  You really ought to be using `.find(selector)` and a selector rather than grabbing the first child element or first child node.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zNEyb/1/ These are some of the checkboxes that are supposed to be checked via the select all button.